# Android MaterialRippleLayout disable click on items

Tags: android, material-design

After using `MaterialRippleLayout` library for widgets such as `TextView` or `Botton` or `ListView` items, click event is disabled. for example in below xml layout button click dont work and i can not get callback of onclick.

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button" />
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

this code doesnot work:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Button Clicked !!","");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try adding the click listener to the layout?

Comment: @mvai this is sample and that doesnt work in such as listview items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm found problem. i must be use this code into listview items:

```
app:mrl_rippleInAdapter="true"
```

Example:

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="#8d575757"
    app:mrl_rippleInAdapter="true"
    app:mrl_rippleDuration="250"
    app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="25" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_group_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDrawerItemIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Comment: Not workng for me !! Can you suggest some other solution ? I am getting this exact issue.